# How do I delete the center of the letter A in Adobe Illustrator CS5?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, lettering

I need the center of the letter A in Illustrator to be transparent so you can see the background underneath. Same with letter D, B, O, P, R.

I imported a vector version of a word, and I am able to select the letter but if I click delete button it deletes the whole word.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select the letter and its counter (hole) and choose `Object > Compound Path > Make`.

Comment: this worked! I had to select with the white arrow.

Comment: also I had to hold SHIFT while selecting the hole's path.

Comment: once selected I can use the shortcut CTRL+8

Answer (score 3):

Window → Pathfinder

Select your letter.

Click on "divide." That should punch a hole in the middle of your solid R or A.

Click on the WHITE arrow (Direct Selection). Click on the LINE around the counter space (the open spot you want to see through) and delete.

Comment: unfortunately this method did not work for me. Thank you though!